# When to persist data in Flutter (onPause equivalent)

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I'm writing a Flutter app geared for mobile devices. I'm used to the Android paradigm where you persist all changes made by the user in `onPause`, which is basically called whenever the current screen goes into the background. I cannot find a Flutter equivalent.

All examples I see have a "Submit" button of sorts, but I would expect an app to save data when I press the back or home buttons (or if I press a save icon in the app bar).

Where do Flutter apps normally persist the state to storage?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WidgetsBindingObserver` to get the `AppLifecycleState.paused`:

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        _saveState();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
    }
  }

  void _saveState() {
    // Save state here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            _saveState();
            return true;
          },
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Another option will be to use [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc), which will automatically save the state for you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it in an Android emulator, but `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` never gets called - I tried clicking on the arrow on the top left which basically pops the route off the stack. I set a breakpoint on `addObserver`, that gets called.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I wonder - that seems like an uncommon way to do it. Is this the standard pattern in Flutter? The normal Android pattern is very well defined - you save your data in `onPause()`. Does Flutter not have a similar pattern for all apps to use?

Comment: This is how native Android apps work, and virtually every "first steps" guide mentions that. From the official docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#saving-persistent-state). Many apps don't have a "save" button, they just store the state when you leave the screen, for example with the back button. Flutter must have a similar concept, I'm looking for what Flutter apps normally do in this case.